# Display specific value in a data frame if there are two that match certain criteria

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
product<-c("ab","ab","ab","ac","ac","ac")
shop<-c("sad","sad","sad","sadas","fghj","xzzv")
category<-c("a","a","a","c","b","b")
tempr<-c(35,35,14,24,14,5)
value<-c(0,0,-6,8,4,0)
store<-data.frame(product,shop,category,tempr,value)



product  shop category tempr value
1      ab   sad        a    35     0
2      ab   sad        a    35     0
3      ab   sad        a    14    -6
4      ac sadas        c    24     8
5      ac  fghj        b    14     4
6      ac  xzzv        b     5     0
```

I want to transform this dataframe in a way that I will keep the unique product names and turn shop names from field values to column names. I want to fill this data frame with a combination of `tempr` and its relative `value` but only for the value that is not 0 otherwise the cells should be empty. The cells should also be empty in case that a product does not exist in a shop. An example of the final form is:

```
store2
  product    sad sadas  fghj xzzv
1      ab 14(-6)                 
2      ac        24(8) 14(4)
```

**EDIT:**

In this example I use `product` as rows and `shop` as column but my goal is to produce the combinations mentioned below: `shop` as rows and `product` as columns, `category` as row and `product` as column and the opposite, `category` as row and `shop` as column and the opposite.

An approach is:

```
store2 <- matrix(NA,ncol=length(unique(store$shop)),nrow=length(unique(store$product)))
colnames(store2) <- unique(store$shop)
rownames(store2) <- unique(store$product)

for(i in 1:ncol(store)) {
  store2[store[i,'product'],store[i,'shop']] <- paste0(store[i,c('tempr')],'(',store[i,'value'],')')
}
```

However, as you  noticed I have records that have the same `product` and `shop`, but different `tempr` and `value` numbers (`ab-sad`). The problem is that they overwrite each other. In that case (same `name`,same `shop` but different `tmpr`-`value`) the non-zero case should prevail. For example 170(62) should be dispalyed instead of 170(0) if they both exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reproduces your expected output:

```
library(tidyverse)
store %>%
    mutate(shop = factor(shop, levels = unique(shop))) %>%
    filter(value != 0) %>%
    mutate(val = sprintf("%s(%s)", tempr, value)) %>%
    select(product, shop, val) %>%
    group_by(product) %>%
    complete(shop) %>%
    spread(shop, val)
#        # A tibble: 2 x 5
## Groups:   product [2]
#  product sad    sadas fghj  xzzv
#  <fct>   <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 ab      14(-6) NA    NA    NA
#2 ac      NA     24(8) 14(4) NA
```

---

To address your comment, if we replace `shop` by `category` we get

```
library(tidyverse)
store %>%
    mutate(category = factor(category, levels = unique(category))) %>%
    filter(value != 0) %>%
    mutate(val = sprintf("%s(%s)", tempr, value)) %>%
    select(product, category, val) %>%
    group_by(product) %>%
    complete(category) %>%
    spread(category, val)
## A tibble: 2 x 4
## Groups:   product [2]
#  product a      c     b
#  <fct>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>
#1 ab      14(-6) NA    NA
#2 ac      NA     24(8) 14(4)
```

Comment: this solution works but when i try to replace "shop" with "category" it doesn't in comparison with the proposed approach

Comment: @firmo23 Why do you replace `shop` with `category`? The example in your post is based on the values in `shop`.

Comment: my fault that I did not mention then but I want to be able to use the category as well with the same way that I use product and shop. If you check my approach and replace shop or product with category it works.

Comment: @firmo23 I can't reproduce; if I replace `shop` with `category` it reproduces the output I get when I replace `shop` with `category` in your approach. I've updated my post to illustrate.

Comment: sorry I mean the replacement in my approach in the Q above not in your solution. I will edit my question

Comment: @firmo23 Yes I understood that. If I replace `shop` with `category` in your *original* question, the output is the same as with my updated approach.

Comment: Ok i editted my Q in order to explain exactly my goal. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179867/discussion-between-firmo23-and-maurits-evers).